# Where should I store my JWT in 2019 and is the localStorage really not secure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, session, authentication

Interesting topic. 
Since I'm creating my first real bigger project with a *Node.js Api* and *React Redux Client* I need authentication.

**Now I'm at the point where I don't know how to handle authentication "the right way".**

Since I read many topics about it but the oppinions differ.

So at first there are the people that say instantly: **Don't use localStorage with JWT.**

For example here is an article: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Here is another article from auth0: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens

But then I digged deeper into the wide world of authentication and I found many people stating:

> "localStorage is as secure as a cookie"

For example from the first article the first comment, the third reply (here is a link: https://dev.to/jondubois/comment/373l )

I mean he got a point right? After reading that and some other articles and comments that say it's perfectly fine to store it in localStorage if you are not a bank with very sensible data.

**So here I'm in 2019, not a beginner but also not an experienced developer, asking myself how I should implement this authentication flow without beeing too over compliacated (there are flows for storing the jwt into a httpOnly cookie for example) but on the other hand also not very easy to hack.**

I'm trying to create a forum application. You can register, create your own forum and then other users can register for this forum. So basic authentication where I just send the user_id and token with the JWT.

I would really appreciate to here you oppinions and your recommendations guys.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looked for this answer too, and finally, I found really interesting and helpful articles about the security of JWT token, that is:
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179487/store-splitted-jwt-for-csrf-protection-and-refresh-strategy
- https://medium.com/@jcbaey/authentication-in-spa-reactjs-and-vuejs-the-right-way-e4a9ac5cd9a3
TL;DR you should store 1st part of token in cookies with `httpOnly: true` parameter and rest of token in cookies without `httpOnly` argument and Javascript can take and use in the browser your JWT payload information.

Comment: This article is good but I'd like to link the article referenced in your article that goes into more detail just so people don't gloss over it as I found it more helpful https://medium.com/lightrail/getting-token-authentication-right-in-a-stateless-single-page-application-57d0c6474e3

Answer (score -2):

Storing JWT at the early stages is as simple as you need it to be. Store it in localstorage as a hash which is sent back from the server. Not the plain JWT token. And make use of `httpOnly`.